# visual studio 2013 professional

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Hi All and apologies if this has been asked already, but I can't find a comprehensive answer anywhere.
I require the ability to develop Desktop applications as well as ASP.NET web projects, I have tried the express versions of the Desktop and Web versions but would like to deploy these projects in a business environment and I am aware that the express licence does not permit this. 
So my question is, Does Visual studio 2013 professional allow the development of both Desktop and Web applications or do I need to buy two versions of Visual Studio 2013?
Thanks for taking the time to read this post.

Comment: Yes VS2013 does allow you to create both "desktop" and web deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Feature Comparison chart for the various editions of Visual Studio, it shows that the Ultimate, Premium and Professional editions of Visual Studio all support development for web and various types of desktop applications.   The entire list is in the 'Development Platform Support' section.

This feature comparison will also show you all the features that you may or not need in your development practice.

http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs